# Can CKEditor's context menu be displayed in "source" mode?

Tags: ckeditor, contextmenu

I have a custom context menu that works well in "wysiwyg" mode that I'd like to also show in "source" mode.

But I see that the editor is pretty much turned off in "source" mode and the text is just displayed in `textarea`. So Im guessing the answer to the question is "no" but would like confirmation.

Anyone had success in stripping back the editor to make "wysiwg" mode look and act like "source" mode via the initial editor configuration? So no HTML tags inserted. (That would let me keep the context menu.)

**PS**

My present solution is to use http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html over a normal text area where I can. Means generating two menu formats though and leaves the "source" mode that I wanted to use for JSON editing in one place missing the menu.

Comment: I would try to do the opposite and enable the context menu on the textarea as that seems less complex.

Comment: @AlfonsoML Yeah I'm looking at that now. The down side is generating two versions of the menu data, one for CKEditor and one for e.g. https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/.